# ember model not being found in store in route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

What i feel like I am doing is very basic yet I'm getting an undefined object everytime, I have an application called Example and have defined an ApplicationRoute:

```
Example.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var user = this.store.find('user',1);
        console.log("username: " + user.username);
        return { user: user };
    }
});
```

And My Model:

```
var attr = DS.attr

Example.User = DS.Model.extend({

    //logged in state can be loggedIn, loggedOff, pending, failed
    loggedInState: attr('string'),
    token: attr('string'),
    username: attr('string'),
    firstName: attr('string'),
    lastName: attr('string'),
    email: attr('string'),
    isLoggedIn: Em.computed.match('loggedInState', /loggedIn/)
});
```

And lastly a FIXTURE:

```
Example.User.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        username: 'jxnagl',
        loggedInState: 'loggedOn',
        firstName: 'Jared',
        lastName: 'Nagle',
        token: '1234',
        email: 'jared.nagle@example.com'
    }
]
```

It is my understanding that this FIXTURE will be present in the store by the time the model hook is called in the Application Route, But when i access my application, I get the following message in my console:

```
"username: undefined"
```

Is there something I'm missing? Ember's documentation shows similar examples and I don't see a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem here was the ember-auth plugin I had a dependency on. It was somehow interferring my application. Removing this plugin solved the problem for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

"find" returns promise.

```
var user = this.store.find('user', 1).then(function(user){
    console.log('username: ' + user.get('username'));
});
```

I think your Route should be like

```
Example.ApplicationRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user',1);
    }
});
```